# Actionbarsherlock libs error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am implementing the `action bar sherlock`, I am having a problem I didn't have before though. When first implementing the action bar sherlock on a project, I could easily delete the `jar` file on the `libs`, and that would remove the `jar mismatch`. But now working on a new project, I cannot delete the jar file. The following error appears:

```
Cannot delete android-support-v4.jar
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003396/import-r-cannot-be-resolved-when-i-import-actionbarsherlock/16003930#16003930

Answer (score 0):

### delete `android-support-v4.jar` from your Project not from actionbarsherlock lib

1. close your project
2. restart eclipse
3. open your project
4. delete `android-support-v4.jar` from your Project

### this is simple and easy way...