# Reference library project

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working on an Android 4.1.2 project, where I'm trying to add a reference to [this github project](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)

Following [this guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject), I've imported the project into the same workspace, and I'm able to select and add the library and get a green checkmark. When I press "Apply" or "OK" the dialog closes, and nothing happens (no rebuild). Then, when I again try to see if it's added, it's not there - not even with a red cross.

I've tried running the project anyway, but it gives me `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshGridView`

First I choose the library, get the green checkmark
[image]

Then I press "Apply" and "OK", and dialog just closes and don't build. When trying to see if library was added, it's not there:
[image]
Any suggestions about what's wrong?

Comment: did you clean and build? did you add the project to your buildpath?

Comment: I've tried building and cleaning. I've not manually added the project to my buildpath for my own project, am I supposed to do that? In that case where?

Comment: @Thomas no don't add it manually. You need to refer the library in your android project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you or did you not check the "Is Library" option?

Comment: The library I'm referencing has "Is Library" checked and is a indeed showing up with a green checkmark. My own project is not set to "Is Library".

Comment: So, you added your library to your project you want to use it with, right? Could you take a screen shot of the error or post an error log?

Comment: No errors, the library just isn't added/saved. See screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference that library in your android project. Assuming you have imported the library project to eclipse, right click on your project, goto properties, choose android , click add, browse and add the library project.

Clean and build and run. Check if you need to add support library for running on lower versions

Comment: See added pictures. That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: refer you library project in your android project by following the above steps.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing? Have you read the question, seen the pictures?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003396/import-r-cannot-be-resolved-when-i-import-actionbarsherlock/16003930#16003930. i have used actionbar sherlock library. the link shows how to do it. its the same procedure for refering pull to refresh library

Comment: Have you seen the screenshots I've posted and read the problem I have? What you suggest is what I'm already doing as far as I can see?

Comment: @Thomas yes i have seen it.

Comment: OK, what is the difference from what I'm doing to what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Import the library and your project in the same work space. then clean the project and try to add library by the same process you are doing(Properties --> Android --->Add). 
Also try restart eclipse.