# Actionbarsherlock ADT22 NoClassDefFountError com.actionbarsherlock.R$Styleable

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

Following are properties of ABS and my project
ADT 22
ABS version 4.3.1
ABS is a library with Android Private Libraries checked in "Build Path - Order and Export"
ABS Target API 17
Project Android Private Libraries checked in "Build Path - Order and Export"
Project Target API 17
ProGuard is off

I did clean build of both ABS and project, eclipse restart yet I get the following error.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:343)

Prashant

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22. try this if it helps

Comment: I have the same config.

Comment: BUT, I created another project, copied files from old...and it is working! First time in my android development I had to do this!!

Comment: I solve this problem with:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003396/import-r-cannot-be-resolved-when-i-import-actionbarsherlock